# leaflet markercluster error: Uncaught TypeError: this.callInitHooks is not a function

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, markerclusterer, leaflet.markercluster

I'm trying to show markercluster on my map but keep recieving error

```
Class.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: this.callInitHooks is not a function
at Object.i [as MarkerClusterGroup] (Class.js:26)
at MarkerOnMap (functions.js:69)
at CreateMarkers (app.js:171)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:1)
```

funcrion and all are ok with markers, i can recieve data correctly, but i keep getting an error like this for `Class.js` and before that for     `var markers = L.MarkerClusterGroup();` that said `MarkerClusterGroup(); is not  function`
I've tried changing the order of calling my cdn's like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
<script src="script/config.js"></script>
<!-- Load Leaflet from CDN -->
<script src="script/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="script/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- marker Cluster CDN -->
<script src="script/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
<!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
<script src="script/esri-leaflet.js"></script>
<!--- amCharts CDN -->
<script src="script/core.js"></script>
<script src="script/charts.js"></script>
<script src="script/maps.js"></script>
<script src="script/animated.js"></script>
```

and `app.js` is called before the `</body>` tag

but still not correct...
I've had this issue before and asked it on [stackoverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64567170/leaflet-markercluster-doesnt-display)
it worked then, but now the solution is not working...

I've tried two different codes:

```
var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup();

for (var i=0; i<ODO.length ; i++){
    for (var i in ODO) {
        var latlng = L.latLng({ lat: ODO[i].LastX, lng: ODO[i].LastY }).addTo(markerClusters);
        
    L.marker( latlng ).addTo(map);
}
}
```

and:

```
for (var i in ODO) {
    var latlng = L.latLng({ lat: ODO[i].LastX, lng: ODO[i].LastY });

    L.marker( latlng ).addTo(map);
}
var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup().addTo(map);
for ( var i = 0; i < ODO.length ; i++ )
{
    var popup = ODO[i].branchcode +
                '<br/><b>prd:</b> ' + ODO[i].saleprd +
                '<br/><b>year :</b> ' + ODO[i].saleyear;

    var map = L.marker( [ODO[i].LastX, ODO[i].LastY] )
                    .bindPopup( popup );

    markerClusters.addLayer( map );
}

map.addLayer( markerClusters );
markerClusterLayer = L.markerClusterGroup({
    disableClusteringAtZoom: 13
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot to add `new`, it should look like: `var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();`

Else you can the shortcut version with a lowercase `M`:

`var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();`

**EDIT**

Your code it a little bit confusing ... Change your code to (delete all what you have posted above):

```
var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup({
    disableClusteringAtZoom: 13
}).addTo(map);

for ( var i = 0; i < ODO.length ; i++ ){
    var popup = ODO[i].branchcode +
                '<br/><b>prd:</b> ' + ODO[i].saleprd +
                '<br/><b>year :</b> ' + ODO[i].saleyear;

    var marker= L.marker( [ODO[i].LastX, ODO[i].LastY] )
                    .bindPopup( popup );

    markerClusters.addLayer( marker);
}
```

PS: If this not works, please say what not working

Comment: no, it doesn't display in both ways... my code is like this now: var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup();

    for (var i=0; i<ODO.length ; i++){
        for (var i in ODO) {
            var latlng = L.latLng({ lat: ODO[i].LastX, lng: ODO[i].LastY }).addTo(markerClusters);
            
        L.marker( latlng ).addTo(map);
    }
    }

Comment: I've added your code, but this time I get the MarkerClusterGroup() is not a finction

Comment: Then you had not copied it right, because it works for me

Comment: i did... ummm I have two files. one is app.js where I have codes for each page or each part like map, etc in . I have my map call function code in this file called Init_Map. but, I made the marker function in another script file . because I wanted this function to only work when I click on a button. first,it recieves data from ajax-url and my json data, then it should display the markerclusters on map depending on what data it recieved. is it possible that it can't read the map when in another script file?

Comment: I've updated the question here :[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64822586/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-addlayer-of-undefined?noredirect=1#comment114609164_64822586]

Comment: It depends how you are scripting. In Vanilla JS you can read the map variable if it is defined in a script !before! the other script is executed.

Comment: can you please create a demo on jsfiddle.net or on a server, else it would be heavy to help ...

Comment: umm I have data from server... using sample data can't affect the code or change the results, right? if so, I'm making a jsfiddle sample.

Comment: okk here is my JsFiddle sample. when the marker cluster is in function, nothing displays but when you delete the function the makers will be shown(these are not clusters I could only add two markers,sorry) [https://jsfiddle.net/depie/zdLge50u/9/]