# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm trying to use leaflet markercluster. but when I run it, gives me an error as:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined
```

my code in functions.js is:

```
for (var i in ODO) {
    var latlng = L.latLng({ lat: ODO[i].LastX, lng: ODO[i].LastY });

    L.marker( latlng ).addTo(map);
}
var markerClusters = new L.MarkerClusterGroup().addTo(map);
for ( var i = 0; i < ODO.length ; i++ )
{
    var popup = ODO[i].branchcode +
                '<br/><b>دوره:</b> ' + ODO[i].saleprd +
                '<br/><b>سال :</b> ' + ODO[i].saleyear;

    var map = L.marker( [ODO[i].LastX, ODO[i].LastY] )
                    .bindPopup( popup );

    markerClusters.addLayer( map );
}

map.addLayer( markerClusters );
markerClusterLayer = L.markerClusterGroup({
    disableClusteringAtZoom: 13
}).addTo(map);
```

and the order of calling cdn is:

```
<!---leaflet css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
crossorigin=""/>
<!---marker cluster css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
<script src="script/config.js"></script>
<!-- Load Leaflet from CDN -->
<script src="script/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="script/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- marker Cluster CDN -->
<script src="script/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
<!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
<script src="script/esri-leaflet.js"></script>
<!--- amCharts CDN -->
<script src="script/core.js"></script>
<script src="script/charts.js"></script>
<script src="script/maps.js"></script>
<script src="script/animated.js"></script>
```

also, I have the leaflet layer code in my app.js like this:

```
function Init_Map()
{

    map = L.map('map').setView( [36.564012,53.060300], 8);
// add the OpenStreetMap tiles
        L.tileLayer('http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
        }).addTo(map);
    }
```

does anyone know the reason for this error?

Comment: Can you confirm that the error is in the line: `map.addLayer( markerClusters );` Because it seems that map variable is not initialized in the context, maybe `map` should be a global variable of your script

Comment: can you remove the "new" from this line "new L.MarkerClusterGroup().addTo(map);"

Comment: I tried to remove but would get the error: MarkerClusterGroup() is not defined

Comment: @CalvinNunes can it be because I made the cluster function in another file? what can I do if I want to get the map vlue still? because I want this function to work when I click on a button. first, it will recieve the data from my ajax-url and json data, and then this function will make it show on map

Comment: @Depie probably... I would have the funcion `Init_Map` in the same file of the one that uses `map.addLayer(...` and I would create the `map` variable as global... Or, you can make your `Init_Map` return the `map` variable, then you can store map in another place that calls the function as `let map = Init_Map()`

Comment: I've made an example jsfiddle that kinda shows my pronlem... when you delete the function the markers display, but when I have it, it doesn't show anything[https://jsfiddle.net/depie/zdLge50u/17/]

Comment: wowww that worked!! i used Init_Map(); at the end of my function and it worked!! thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I called the `Init_Map();` function in the last part of my markerclustering function and it just worked